# Laravel show all images from folder

Tags: php, laravel

I upload from vue 4-5 images to different folders in laravel.

```
public function uploadImageso2orders(Request $request, $id)
   {
       $o2order = O2order::findOrFail($id);
       $name =  $o2order->contactname;
       $name2 = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
       $image = $request->file('file');
       $imageName = $name2.'.'.time().'.'.$image->extension();
       $wwwPath = 'https://api2.api.sk/storage/';
       $image->move(storage_path('app/o2/servisne' . '/' . $name2),$imageName);
       $imagePath = 'https://api2.api.sk/storage/app/o2/' . ('servisne' . '/' . $name2);
       $o2order->servisny = $imagePath;
       $o2order->save();
   }
```

This is working fine. In storage/app/o2/servisne_listy/ is folder created and multiple images stored. In sql is written full path to this folder.

I need to show this image or images, sometimes its one sometimes more, not same.

I have this:

```
public function showImageso2orders(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $o2order = O2order::findOrFail($id);
        $servisny =  $o2order->servisny;
        return response()->json(['servisny' => $servisny], 200);
    }
```

**Its shows only the path from sql, but i need path to every file which is in this directory.**

Thanks

Comment: You are saving the images full path in your database table, right?

Comment: I am saving only directory path, without images names.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you

```
$path = storage_path('app/o2/servisne');
$files = File::files($path)
```